# printing to thermal printer from windows mobile 6 device

Tags: printing

I am building a windows mobile 6 application for electronic ordering. I need to print an order from windows device to a thermal printer. Since there is no print method to wm 6 what should I do to develop printing? My printer is ESC/POS. Can anyone please inform me what options I have? I am new to this and I am realy confused..

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The device should only have to send information to a centralized server which will then offload the printing appropriately.  At least in my opinion at no point should a mobile device be able to interface with a printer from the electronic ordering perspective.